# Enabling Account Role Optimization

Tags: customer-community, roles

I really want to use ARO as defined here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_partners_optimize_roles.htm&type=5

The issue is that I don't see `Use person role for first site user in partner and customer accounts` within `Sharing Settings` and I can't find any other documentation about why this option isn't appearing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Salesforce, the setting is now labeled `Minimize the number of roles created, which improves performance by cutting down processing loads` and enables the same functionality.